# Why is the fetched value from mysql via PHP(pdo) different from the value I've just updated?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I store a large file (36.5MB zip archive) into a mysql longblob field.

There are some files that I can't fetch the same result via a select statement on PHP (pdo).

I use PHP 7.0.15 and MySQL 5.6.35.

Here is the code.

```php
$original_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path));
$nickname = 'nickname';

/** @var PDO $pdo */
$pdo = DB::instance()->connection();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('update dump_data set data=? where nickname=?');
$stmt->execute([$original_data, $nickname]);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select data from dump_data where nickname=?');
$stmt->execute([$nickname]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$fetched_data = $result['data'];

echo "original_data ===\n";
var_dump($original_data);
echo "fetched_data ===\n";
var_dump($fetched_data);
echo "compare ===\n";
var_dump($original_data == $fetched_data);
```

And, here is the result.

```
original_data ===
string(48701976) "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"...

fetched_data ===
string(48701976) "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"...

compare ===
bool(false)
```

For the dump data is snipped, it seems to be the same, but the fetched data is actually different from the original data.

When I save a smaller data into the field, I can successfully the right result.

```
original_data ===
string(19) "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

fetched_data ===
string(19) "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

compare ===
bool(true)
```

Why is the fetched value different from the value I've just updated?
Did anyone come across the same problem?

Comment: I’m not really sure what the problem is with your code but as a simple suggestion: you should not Base64-encode your data. BLOB fields are already equipped to handle binary data. Using a Base64-encode will just blow up your storage requirements in the DB. PHP can handle binary data in string perfectly well. Also, try comparing the data via `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Thank you for your comment. At first, I stored a not encoded data into the longblob field, and I noticed the fetched data corrupted. It is simply because I want to see the actual data.

Comment: imo, When using BLOB's is the only time to be using `bindParam` with PDO and also supply the parameter type. The reason I do this is that BLOB's are handled differently that string fields by the calling language and the database. i.e. they are treated as files. So, i like to give 'clues' to all concerned that BLOB's are being processed.

Comment: @RyanVincent https://gist.github.com/omoon/69e5b39caf32e4a6aabd2410a0ef5851 I found that when fetched 16777212 bytes data, a null byte was added to the end of the data. Is this a bug of PHP?

Comment: I have no idea. It looks interesting. ;-/ The issue is that PHP is built on top of 'C'. There can be some confusion with PHP when trying to make string routines 'binary safe'. It will be all fixed eventually... ? Like you I tend to not allow binary zero as a charcter in strings I store in PHP. So, I take the hit of `base64`. Or store large  binary information outside the database with links to it that I can check it is valid.

Comment: I've just reported this issue to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74086 .